# Javascript - Cannot figure out how to implement a while condition for turn based actions

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, counter

Just wanna say first off you're awesome and thank you in advance. Now onto my problem. I am making a turn based RPG game using HTML5, Javascript, and some Jquery. I'm good on mostly everything like damage, taking turns, etc. except when I try to emulate a buff/debuff. Think of a video game character in a turn based RPG like say Final Fantasy or something that gets poisoned and takes damage every turn. Or a character that drinks a potion and does 5+ damage for 3 turns. I have done what I believe is extensive research and have tried messing around with different techniques listed below:

1) setInterval (Why it doesn't work for me): It uses milliseconds but I can't seem to implement that into a turn based action.

2) setTimeout (Why it doesn't work for me): Like setInterval it depends on milliseconds passed not counters like times something is clicked.

3) While and For Loops (Why it doesn't work for me): I first make a variable that counts the number of times my attack function is clicked, increments that count by 1 and then I apply the debuff. Say for this example, evil character's health -5 for 3 turns and then after the loop is executed reset. so something like (this is watered down by the way to focus on the topic at hand). The prevalent problem I seem to be having as well is my loops seem to infinitely loop or when I use either return false; or break; nothing happens when the code reaches that loop for some reason. Help please!

```
//This is a counter for detecting times attack function executed
var attackCounter = 0;
var dragonHealth = 30; 
// Returns a number between 1-10
var bleedChance = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 

// stored into a variable to call later in different function
var attack1 = function() {
$("#kAttack1").click(function() {
// Apply regular damage of -5 to dragons health 
dragonHealth -= 5; 
// Increment turn counter by 1
attackCounter++;
// If I get an 8 or above (%20 chance) I apply the bleed buff of -5 
// health for 3 turns
if (bleedChance >= 8) {
attackCounter = 0;
// THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK (What do I need to execute so that (1) I 
// apply -5 health to the dragon for 3 turns (2) After I reset the 
// attack counter to 0 how can I make sure that if bleedChance is called
// during the current 3 turns the dragon is taking -5 bleed damage that 
// bleed damage isn't called again thus stacking the effect undesirably
// And lastly (3) when the effect is over allow bleedChance to be able
// to be activated again if I get over. Again my entire game is turn 
//based not in real time. 
}

});
};
```

Comment: What function executes the turns? Is each turn triggered separately?

Comment: Can you not use setTimeout/setInterval and then just put an if/else in it to see if the turn is completed?

Comment: Try to capture the complete state of your game in an object, and don't mutate that. Every turn, build a new object with the new state. Give each turn a number, and store in which round an effect was applied or until which it will last.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

```
//declare at the top
var bleedEffects = []
```

...

```
if (bleedChance >= 8) {
    attackCounter = 0;
    //add to the bleeds
    bleedEffects.push({turnsLeft:3});
}
//loop through the bleeds starting from the end
for(var i = bleedEffects.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    //bleed the dragon
    dragonHealth -= 5;
    //decrement the turns
    bleedEffects[i].turnsLeft--;
    //check if we have no turns left
    if(bleedEffects[i].turnsLeft == 0)
        //remove from the array
        bleedEffects.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help but I have to say the winner is FeleMortis! I guess what I was missing is .push which I wasn't familiar with until I googled it a couple of minutes ago. I'm going to add this function inside of my knight attack A.K.A. ("#kAttack").click function and hopefully we can make this dragon bleed!

Comment: @user5490491 Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! thanks again FelesMortis. 
For those who might stumble upon this thread in the future below is the script I used to apply a debuff of -5 health to an enemy for 3 turns and while those 3 turns are being applied you cannot stack up anymore of the same effect.

```
var bleedEffects = []
var attackCounter = 4;
var dragonHealth = 100;

$("#kAttack1").click(function() {

attackCounter ++;
console.log("Attack Counter Is Now :" + attackCounter);
var bleedChance = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
console.log("Bleed Chance Is:" + bleedChance *  10 + "%");

if ((bleedChance >= 8) && (attackCounter >= 4)) {
    attackCounter = 0;
    console.log("Attack Counter Reset To :" + attackCounter);
    //add to the bleeds
    bleedEffects.push({turnsLeft:3});
}
//loop through the bleeds starting from the end
for(var i = bleedEffects.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    //bleed the dragon
    dragonHealth -= 5;
    console.log("Dragon's Health Is Now :" + dragonHealth);
    console.log("Dragons bleeds for " + (-attackCounter + 2) + "more turns");
    //decrement the turns
    bleedEffects[i].turnsLeft--;
    //check if we have no turns left
    if(bleedEffects[i].turnsLeft == 0)
        //remove from the array
        bleedEffects.splice(i, 1);
}
});
```